# Время посещения учеников по возрастанию

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть такой запрос:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM stud WHERE day1='Пятница' or day2='Пятница' or day3='Пятница' ORDER BY time1 ASC, time2 ASC, time3 ASC";
```

Нужно рассортировать время в таблице по возрастанию.  Для первого ученика это может быть второй урок по расписанию недели day1 и time1, а для другого третий день day3 и time3. Но у обоих приход к примеру в Пятницу 15:00.  **Как правильно прописать ORDER BY ASC для трех полей time1, time2, time3, чтобы в таблице было по возрастанию?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вдруг предполагается, что в строке из трех полей `time-X` заполнено только одно, то вам в помощь `IFNULL` или `COALESCE`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать вложенный запрос, типа такого:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, time1 as timeN FROM stud WHERE day1='Пятница'
  UNION
  SELECT *, time2 as timeN FROM stud WHERE day2='Пятница'
  UNION
  SELECT *, time3 as timeN FROM stud WHERE day3='Пятница'  
) ORDER BY timeN ASC
```